# R, iterating over the row vectors of a matrix

Tags: r, vector, matrix, fold, higher-order-functions

I have some vector `vect` and I want to iterate over the row vectors `v`of a matrix and calculate:

`cov(v, vect)`.

I tried:

```
for(vect in mat2)     #where mat2 is a 215 by 31 matrix
```

However, each vector appeared to be a scalar with value 1.

1. How do I iterate over the row vectors of a matrix?
2. To make this even better, since I am interested in calculating the sum of `cov(v, vect)` where v is a row vector, how can I use the higher-order functions `left-fold` and `right-fold`

Comment: Have you actually read `?for` ?  You need to think a little about what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for `apply` ?

```
apply(mat2, 1, function(v)cov(v,vect))
```

Comment: Possibly, I am looking for the sum of `cov(v, vect)`

Comment: No, `vect` is some arbitrary vector (used for supervision) and every vector `v` in `mat2` has the same 31 dimensions as `vect`

Comment: I want to sum the `covariance(v, vect)`, for every row vector `v` in `mat2`. I think you may mean that this is the covariance matrix but I think of this more as a vector of corresponding covariances, or a list of corresponding covariances.

Comment: Maybe i need to build this covariance vector first?

Comment: of course, `cov` of two vectors does not return a matrix. Is this what you mean: `sum(apply(mat2, 1, function(v)cov(v,vect)))` ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand that vect is a separate vector from mat2:

```
apply(mat2, 1, function(v) cov(v, vect))
```

The apply function allows you to apply an arbitrary function over the rows (if the second argument is 1) or columns (if 2) or a higher dimension (if >2).  It is also much faster than using a loop.