# Iterate over columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a function

```
function (x, y) { ... }
```

which expects two vectors `x` and `y` and returns a value calculated from them.

I want to apply this function pairwise to the column vectors of two matrices `xs` and `ys`. From [R, iterating over the row vectors of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005594/r-iterating-over-the-row-vectors-of-a-matrix) I found `mapply()` but this seems to apply the function pairwise to each element of the matrix. Instead, I want to apply the function to an entire column. How do I do this?

For clarification, here's a contrived example:

```
xs <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
ys <- matrix(c(25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
dot <- function(x, y) sum(x*y)
```

Comment: A little more context (and preferably a [mcve]) would help. Note that if worse comes to worse, you can transpose both matrices and then iterate over the rows.

Comment: @JohnColeman I was working on that. I edited the question with a contrived example. I don't know enough R to fill in the details of the `dot` function, though.

Comment: The `dot` would simply be `dot <- function(x,y) sum(x*y)` (if it isn't already built-in)

Comment: @JohnColeman Makes sense. This is a trivial detail that doesn't really matter to my question. But it makes the question more concrete and easier to understand.

Comment: So what's the output you want? And you want it as a matrix?

Comment: @camille In the case of my code example, I want a list/matrix/vector (doesn't really matter) with two numbers that are the dot products of corresponding column vectors of the input matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
xs <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
ys <- matrix(c(25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
dot <- function(x, y) {
  sum(x*y)
}

dots <- sapply(1:ncol(xs),function(i) dot(xs[,i],ys[,i])) #dots = c(158, 437)
```

Answer (score 4):

Nobody yet mentioned `asplit` (added in R 3.6.0) - the function made specifically for this case.

Example:

```
mapply(dot, asplit(xs, 2), asplit(ys, 2))
```

Same but using rows:

```
mapply(dot, asplit(xs, 1), asplit(ys, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple `for` loop

```
v1 <- numeric(ncol(xs))
for(i in seq_along(v1)) v1[i] <- dot(xs[,i], ys[,i])
v1
#[1] 158 437
```

---

Or with vectorized option

```
colSums(xs * ys)
#[1] 158 437
```

Comment: Your second example solves the specific problem of calculating the dot product of the column vectors. But that was just a contrived example, so doesn't help me with the more general problem of applying a function to pairs of columns.

Answer (score 1):

mapply expect list or data frame to work on column:

```
mapply(dot,as.data.frame(xs),as.data.frame(ys))

 V1  V2 
158 437
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `mapply` like this:

```
mapply(function(i, x = xs, y = ys) dot(x[,i],y[,i]), 1:ncol(xs))
```

or use `purrr`:

```
purrr::map_dbl(1:ncol(xs), function(i,x,y) dot(x[,i],y[,i]), x = xs, y = ys)
```